# Chrome extension – is it possible to track local file change?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to inject CSS into site upon file change in user's local system. Is it possible with Chrome extension (so far I only found Chrome OS tutorials)?

Comment: Extensions don't have a special API so you can simply poll the file:// URL (assuming the user of your extension has enabled file access in chrome://extensions UI) or use the new File System API.